# generating an index of numerical values contained in a string using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-parsing, string-parsing

I am working on a bit of code for a project right now, and the basic idea is to read the contents out of a file line by line and record the frequencies of each numerical value contained within.  For future analysis it's important for me to know both how many of a value there was and also how often they occurred per line, so I can't treat the file as a "bag of numbers" and just count the total of each.

My initial concept was to generate an empty list, and for each number index along the list that far (number ten would be at valueList[10] etc) and then increment the value in that position for each incidence of the value "10".  It's easy enough for me to capture that information on the line-counter as well to give me line-by-line data as well.

I am (obviously) a newcomer to Python.  I am familiar with other languages but have mostly done embedded programming previously so I'm not knowledgeable about the higher level functions etc.  Is there a "best practice" or more robust way to do this than what I've described?

Cheers, 
Will

Comment: the format of the numbers I am examining is the following: 116 104 105 115 32 109 97 107 101 115 32 105 116 32 111 102 102 105 99 105 97 108 44 32 119 104 105 99 104 32 105 115 32 115 111 32 103 114 101 97 116 46 32 10  That is one line.. lines are of different length depending on what the microcontroller outputs to the log file

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary will be more suitable here, use `collections.Counter()`. Using `list` is not a good idea as you might not know how many unique numbers are present in the text file and for missing digits it may result in sparse list.

Example:

```
In [16]: text="""1                      
2
3
4
5
5
1
2
5
3"""

In [17]: from collections import Counter

In [18]: c=Counter()      

In [19]: for num in text.splitlines():    
    c[num]+=1
   ....:     

In [20]: c
Out[20]: Counter({'5': 3, '1': 2, '3': 2, '2': 2, '4': 1})
```

Comment: `c = Counter(text.splitlines())`

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to use a dictionary than a list...

```
def inc_count(d, number):
    try:
        d[number] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d[number] = 1

def dump_counts(d):
    for k in sorted(d):
        print 'Number %d occurred %d times' % (k, d[k])

>>> d = {}
>>> inc_count(d, 10)
>>> inc_count(d, 10)
>>> inc_count(d, 11)
>>> dump_counts(d)
Number 10 occurred 2 times
Number 11 occurred 1 times
```

Comment: I'm in the process of making this suggestion work, as when I split the string using text.split() to get the individual "words" of the number string they're coming out string and not integer.  But in initial test this seems to be the best solution thus far.  Thank you lots for your help.